# ZFS: Does anyone know how to roll a zvol back in time?

Tags: linux, zfs, data-recovery

I have a ZFS based iSCSI SAN that serves ZVOLs to a bunch of VM servers. Today a network glitch caused all the iSCSI volumes mounted on the clients to go RO. The only way out of that is to shut them all down and restart, often running fsck to get the iSCSI volumes back on-line. Well, fsck decided to thoroughly destroy one of the volumes. So, it does not look like I'm going to be able to fix the mess fsck made.

I've read quite a bit about recovering files on ZFS, however, in this case I'm dealing with ZVOLs, which in a sense is a lot simpler, but I haven't seen anything dealing with trying to roll back the contents of a block device. Any suggestions?

-TIA-

Some dataset details:

```
Dataset zpool1/vm3 [ZVOL], ID 59, cr_txg 12078, 44.6G, 2 objects, rootbp DVA[0]=<6:6c2c4b1e00:200> DVA[1]=<7:487aa4b200:200> [L0 DMU objset] fletcher4 lz4 LE contiguous unique double size=800L/200P birth=7736596L/7736596P fill=2 cksum=4c78779ec:2049fb2de6c:6f2f6c4a44e9:1042484aee3ded

    Deadlist: 1K (512/512 comp)

mintxg 0 -> obj 48
mintxg 1 -> obj 4157

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         0    7    16K    16K  7.00K    16K    6.25  DMU dnode
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         1    5    16K     8K  44.6G   200G   36.45  zvol object
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 26214399

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         2    1    16K    512      0    512  100.00  zvol prop
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 1 entries

                size = 214748364800
```

The system is CentOS 7.1

```
Linux san1srvp01 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 18 13:06:36 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There isn't a relevant snapshot; I figured that went without saying.

The reason that I'm asking the question, and what I'm after relates to articles like this one from [Max Burning](https://www.joyent.com/blog/zfs-forensics-recovering-files-from-a-destroyed-zpool) which delves into object recovery through forensic techniques. This of course relies on no shortage of knoledge of ZFS internals. Most of what I've seen though deals with walking back over file objects which is very different from the objects that implement raw block storage and I have seen next to nothing on the internals related to ZVOLs.

Even if I can't technically "roll back" the changes that fsck made it would at least be helpful to walk back and find some of the key original blocks. This should be possible given ZFS's COW behavior... and sufficient knoledge which I lack, but I don't usually let that stop me.

Comment: Provided that you have ZFS snapshots available, you can roll them back with instructions on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbcxk/index.html

Comment: Any details on what type of ZFS system you're using? OS? Version? ZFS implementation? Because that matters.

Comment: I've updated the original question with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.  It will be messy.

https://gist.github.com/jshoward/5685757

Including the original file now that the link has gone dead.

zfs_revert-0.1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Script for reverting ZFS changes by destroying uberblocks
#Author: Martin Vool
#E-mail: mardicas@gmail.com
#Version: 0.1
#Date: 16 November 2009


import time
import subprocess
import sys
import os
#Default blocksize
bs=512
#default total blocks (sorry programming in estonian :-/)
suurus=None

if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    for arg in sys.argv:
        arg=arg.split('=')
        if len(arg) == 1:
            file=arg[0]
        elif arg[0] == '-bs':
            bs=int(arg[1])
        elif arg[0] == '-tb':
            suurus=int(arg[1])
else:
    print 'Usage: zfs_revert.py [-bs=n default:n=512 blocksize] \\n [-tb=n total block size in blocks] [file/device] You have to set -tb'
    exit(1)
print int(bs)
if suurus == None:
    print 'Total block size in blocks is undefined'
    exit(1)
#make solaris use gnu grep.
if os.uname()[0] == 'SunOS':
    grep_cmd='ggrep'
else:
    grep_cmd='grep'


#to format program output
def formatstd(inp):
    inp=inp.split('\n')
    ret=[]
    for line in inp:
        columns=line.split(' ')
        nc=[]
        for c in columns:
            if c != '':
                nc.append(c)
        ret.append(nc)
    return ret


#read blocks from beginning(64mb)
a_count=(256*bs)
#read blocks from end (64mb)
l_skip=suurus-(256*bs)


print 'Total of %s blocks'%suurus
print 'Reading from the beginning to %s blocks'%a_count
print 'Reading from %s blocks to the end'%l_skip

#get the uberblocks from the beginning and end
yberblocks_a=formatstd(subprocess.Popen('sync && dd bs=%s if=%s count=%s | od -A x -x | %s -A 2 "b10c 00ba" | %s -v "\-\-"'%(bs,file, a_count,grep_cmd,grep_cmd), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0])
yberblocks_l=formatstd(subprocess.Popen('sync && dd bs=%s if=%s skip=%s | od -A x -x | %s -A 2 "b10c 00ba" | %s -v "\-\-"'%(bs,file, l_skip,grep_cmd,grep_cmd), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0])


yberblocks=[]

for p in yberblocks_a:
    if len(p) > 0:
        #format the hex address to decmal so dd would eat it.
        p[0]=(int(p[0], 16)/bs)
        yberblocks.append(p)

for p in yberblocks_l:
    if len(p) > 0:
        #format the hex address to decmal so dd would eat it and add the skipped part.
        p[0]=((int(p[0], 16)/bs)+int(l_skip)) #we have to add until the place we skipped so the adresses would mach.
        yberblocks.append(p)
print '----'
#here will be kept the output that you will see later(TXG, timestamp and the adresses, should be 4, might be less)
koik={}
i=0
for p in yberblocks:
    if len(p) > 0:
        if i == 0:#the first output line
            address=p[0]
        elif i == 1:#second output line
            #this is the output of od that is in hex and needs to be reversed
            txg=int(p[4]+p[3]+p[2]+p[1], 16)
        elif i == 2:#third output line
            timestamp=int(p[4]+p[3]+p[2]+p[1], 16)
            try:
                aeg=time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(timestamp))
            except:
                aeg='none'
            if koik.has_key(txg):
                koik[txg]['addresses'].append(address)
            else:
                koik[txg]={
                    'txg':txg,
                    'timestamp':timestamp,
                    'htime': aeg,
                    'addresses':[address]
                }
        if i == 2:
            i=0
        else:
            i+=1
    keys = koik.keys()
    keys.sort()
    
while True:
    keys = koik.keys()
    keys.sort()
    print 'TXG\tTIME\tTIMESTAMP\tBLOCK ADDRESSES'
    for k in keys:
        print '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s'%(k, koik[k]['htime'],koik[k]['timestamp'],koik[k]['addresses'])
    try:
        save_txg=int(input('What is the last TXG you wish to keep?\n'))
        keys = koik.keys()
        keys.sort()
        for k in keys:
            if k > save_txg:
                for adress in koik[k]['addresses']:
                    #wrtie zeroes to the unwanted uberblocks
                    format=formatstd(subprocess.Popen('dd bs=%s if=/dev/zero of=%s seek=%s count=1 conv=notrunc'%(bs, file, adress), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0])
                del(koik[k])
        #sync changes to disc!
        sync=formatstd(subprocess.Popen('sync', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0])
    except:
        print ''
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers  Can you make your answer complete?

Comment: Gave me the knoledge to do a forensic analysis of the past, which yielded enough to manually repair the ext3 inode damage on the ZVOL in place. I had a snapshot after the fsck damage so I just reformatted the ZVOL, cloned the snapshot, then repaired each vm image in the clone, and then copied the repaired vm image files forward to the clean volume.

fsck had trashed the file and directory inodes. A look back in ZFS time revealed copies of the trashed structures and it was mostly just a matter of reconstructing the file and dir inodes.

Answer (score 2):

> There isn't a relevant snapshot; I figured that went without saying.

So, without a snapshot that correlates with a time where the zpool and data are healthy, you don't have any easy recourse or ability to roll back.

Comment: That's true, but I'm not looking for easy, I'm already good at easy, I'm looking for technical details related to the hard way.

Also, for the record, the ZFS dataset object is healthy, the ZVOL is a totally healthy "container". Unfortunately, the owner messed up what he was keeping in it, so I'm looking to walk back his transactions.

Comment: At this point you're stuck with recovering as much data as you can from the filesystem and then restoring the rest from backups or creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

As Tero Kilkanen correctly said in the comments, you need to have a snapshot of the zvol from the time where it was still valid, otherwise your data is lost.

---

Some background:

Snapshots can be created from any dataset - file systems or volumes (zvol), and is itself also a (read-only, dependant) dataset. They are always atomic, so you get the state on a certain point of time for the whole dataset (although for your applications on top it might seem like a hard reset of the disk or system in the worst case), and can be sure that your data integrity is preserved (at least for sync writes, async writes could of course have been discarded partially).

The only difference between zvols and filesystems in this regard is that - as each snapshot always references the whole dataset - you can pick and choose which files to restore from a file system snapshot (mix it with current or older data), but you can only choose to use the whole zvol, because it is like a really big file (theoretically, you could copy byte ranges and merge them yourself, but that would be quite inconvenient). Aside from this "view" on the data (files vs. blocks) the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the zpool import -T option. Beware: this is on the pool, not the zvol. Perhaps you could send your zvol into a new zpool, and use import -T to import it using a different txg.